# How to change the name of a select in a Symfony form?

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony

I made a form with Symfony. I wanted to make sure that select tag can be duplicated. So I made it possible in JavaScript code. I succeeded to give the name I wanted to new selects. But I would like to change the name of the first select also, replace user[wishedlanguages][**name**] by user[wishedlanguages][0].

I tried .setAttibute() and .replace() and had something like this :

```
wishedlanguageselect.setAttribute('name', wishedlanguageselect.name.replace('__name__', '0'))
```

but it didn't work.

[image]

JS code :

```
idcounter = 1;
const wishedlanguageselect = document.getElementById("user_wishedlanguages___name__");
/* wishedlanguageselect.setAttribute('name', wishedlanguageselect.name.replace('__name__', '0')) */
const wishedlanguageslist = document.getElementById('wishedlanguageslist');

document.getElementById("addwishedlanguage").onclick = function() {
    idcounter++
    const newwishedlanguageselect = wishedlanguageselect.cloneNode(true);
    newwishedlanguageselect.setAttribute('name', 'user[wishedlanguages][' + idcounter + ']')
    document.getElementById('wishedlanguageslist').appendChild(newwishedlanguageselect);
    document.getElementById("removewishedlanguage").style.display = "initial";
}

document.getElementById("removewishedlanguage").onclick = function() {
    idcounter--
    wishedlanguageslist.removeChild(wishedlanguageslist.lastElementChild);
    if(idcounter === 1) {
        document.getElementById("removewishedlanguage").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't visible at what point you tried to modify the first select option to have the 0 index. Did you check that the "wishedlanguageselect" is what you expected when you try to modify it? Did you try using the same setAttribute code that works for the cloned nodes instead of using the replace? You probably should also clean up the code to set unique IDs for the select elements (which might also have an impact on this issue depending on at what point the and with what getter the failed part is done).

Comment: Yes, I did everything you said ejuhjav.

Comment: .setAttribute didn't work at all.

Comment: I just pasted exactly my code as it is. You'll see that I left the line that doesn't work in comment.

Comment: So you checked that the instance you have stored is the one where the name contains "__name__" part (by logging the name property etc)? And tried using the same setAttribute style as in the loop ("'user[wishedlanguages][0]" instead of the name replace)?